# android:how to save sdk platform

Tags: android

I want to keep all the installed sdk platforms/docs etc in storage for later use, so that I dont have to download them AGAIN after I install SDK later. How to keep these files and how to restore them later in SDK manager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install any SDK you want using provided SDK manager and do not remove them even you do not use it. These will not disappear by itself unless you explicitly wipe the files out.

Comment: but where in the SDK folders are these files ?

Comment: See Eclipse's Window > Pereferences > Android tab, "SDK Location"

Answer (score 0):

SDK Platfotm, tools, documentation and all other are stored in your SDK folder. If you don't know location of SDK folder check it from Eclipse: Window > Pereferences > Android tab